# State of the Scala development in terms of tooling

Tags: scala, ide

I did my homework and searched for previous posts. There are lot of discussion going on during 2009-2010 and some on 2011 about different preferences what people are using as their IDE/editor when developing scala.

By the looks of it the scala-support and features are pretty fast moving target for editors/IDE's to support. So I though to ask this once again.

What are you guys using for Scala-development? Eclipse/Netbeans/IntelliJ? Anyone using Ensime and Emacs? Any vim-users? What version of scala? What are your requirements and how well the tools can answer those? What would you like to change?

Personally I'm a little tired of huge IDE's and seriously looking for Emacs/Ensime combined with other tools like tmux, sbt and so on.

Comment: While it is interesting question it is badly fits Q&A format.

Comment: Just pick your favorite editor and go with it. You'll have better luck figuring out what support there is for the tool you pick than trying to assert how each tool is doing. Besides, some people are pretty wedded to big IDE, while others are much fonder of lightweight editors.

Comment: Q & A ... Well what ever. You could have left it OPEN give each IDE/ Setup it's own answer and then the votes would give a pretty nice overview. But NO ... Not constructive... Pah

Comment: It would be interesting to make a wiki out of it like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445003/what-scala-blogs-do-you-regularly-follow

Comment: @AndreasScheinert - The only reason I voted to close is because I knew it would be closed soon, and it would be less frustrating if it were quick (rather than get a half-dozen answers over several hours and then see it closed).  I don't like this policy either.  It's possible this might fare better over at http://programmers.stackexchange.com, but, as you say, it would have to be carefully constructed to avoid dragon-breath there too.